# How to update a value in a table to MAX of other rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Consider this table:

```
Declare @Content table (id int, ParentId int, CreatedOn DateTime, LastCommentOn DateTime)

insert into @Content values 
(1, null, GETDATE() - 10, '2001-12-01'),
(2, 1, GETDATE() - 9, GETDATE() - 8),
(3, 1, GETDATE() - 8, GETDATE() - 7),
(4, 1, GETDATE() - 7, GETDATE() - 6),
(5, null, GETDATE() - 6, '2001-12-01'),
(6, 5, GETDATE() - 5, GETDATE() - 4),
(7, 5, GETDATE() - 4, GETDATE() - 3),
(8, null, GETDATE() - 3, '2001-12-01'),
(9, 8, GETDATE() - 2, GETDATE() - 1)
```

I want to update all main content (identified by ParentId is null) to the CreatedOn date of the last comment on that content.

I've tried

```
update @Content m 
set LastCommentOn = MAX(select CreatedOn from @Content c where c.ParentId = m.Id) 
where ParentId is null and LastCommentOn = '2001-12-01'
```

and

```
update @Content 
set LastCommentOn = MAX(select CreatedOn from @Content c where c.ParentId = m.Id) 
from @Content m
where ParentId is null and LastCommentOn = '2001-12-01'
```

but I can't get it to do what I want..

How do I do this in MSSQL please?

(Also, it the query going to be the same on mysql?)

---

The accepted answer worked great on MS SQL, but, on MySql, I couldn't find a way to do it in one statement, I had to split the query into two parts and update.. so this is what worked for me on mysql

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0;

Create temporary table tmpContentDates 

select Max(ParentId) as pid, Max(CreatedOn) as pd
From Content
where ParentId is not null
Group By ParentId; 

update Content as c
    inner join tmpContentDates d on c.Id = d.pid
set c.LastCommentedOn = d.pd
where ParentId is null
    and LastCommentedOn = '2001-12-01';

drop table tmpContentDates;
```

Comment: "Consider this table" => We don't see the meta information of your table, only the values you're filling in. Please also add the missing information.

Comment: @FabianBigler oops, added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried?

```
update @Content 
set LastCommentOn =  
(select MAX(CreatedOn) from @Content c where c.ParentId = m.Id) 
from @Content m
where ParentId is null and LastCommentOn = '2001-12-01'
```

Comment: yours was the only answer that didn't have syntax errors and it also works! I kept adding the whole select inside max instead of max inside select! thanks so much

Comment: No problem! Also, this should be the same query in MySQL, but I'm not 100%

Comment: I only looked at your nested SELECT, assumed the rest of your statement in OP was already syntactically correct when using your 2nd code box. :s

Comment: @Elias MySql doesn't have `From` clause in update.. go figure!

Comment: That's unfortunate. I'm not going to be much help with that! Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Your SQL should be

```
update @Content m 
set LastCommentOn = (select MAX(CreatedOn) from @Content c where c.ParentId = m.Id)
where ParentId is null and LastCommentOn = '2001-12-01'
```

Assuming max works on DateTime

Answer (score 1):

```
update @Content 
set LastCommentOn = MAX(c.CreatedOn) 
from @Content m
inner join @Content c on c.ParentId = m.Id
where ParentId is null and LastCommentOn = '2001-12-01'
```